# Error requesting backend interface using Axios in Vue

Tags: django, vue.js, axios

In mounted, the requested data can be returned normally when the page is loaded

```js
    mounted() {
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/', {params: {'s': 's'}})
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            this.items = response.data
        });
    }
```

In methods, data can not be adjusted, and the back end will report errors

```js
    methods: {
        search: function() {
            axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/', {params: {'s': 's'}})
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
                this.items = response.data
            });
        }
    }
```

The error is as follows:

[image]

Comment: If this requests are identical then maybe 2 sequential requests lead to this error.

Comment: You might want to add a `catch` block there for the axios method, maybe you'll get something more useful out of it.

Comment: Can you add your server side code?